# Si existe informacion de una tabla en otra tabla no se pueda eliminar c#

Tags: c#, visual, studio

Me gustaria saber si me ayudan por favor.
Tengo una tabla Categoria que es foránea a la tabla productos.
Cuando yo elimino una catagoria que ya existe en la lista de productos en mi aplicacion web , me suelta error porque en mi pagina web' Lista de productos' existe dicha 'categoria' que quiero eliminar , como evito ese error?

```
    protected void btnEliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
    {
        try
        {
            using (baseDatoEntities bd = new baseDatoEntities())
            {
                int Codigo = int.Parse(txtCodigo.Text);

                var f = (bd.SpConsultarCategoriaporId(Codigo)).FirstOrDefault();

                var a = (bd.SpConsultarProductoCodigo(Codigo)).FirstOrDefault();

             
                    if (f != null)
                    {
                        bd.SpEliminarCategoria(Codigo);
                        bd.SaveChanges();

                        lblMensaje.Text = "Se ha eliminado con éxito";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblMensaje.Text = "No se pudo eliminar porque ya existe o ya fue eliminado ";
                    }

                }
                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblMensaje.Text = "Hay un error"+ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Publica tu código y el mensaje de error original.

Comment: Saludos. Debes eliminar de `Productos` los registros que estn usando la `FK` ´(que corresponden a `PK`en `Categoria`); otra opción es que temporalmente deshabilites el `CONSTRAINT` que valida ello igual eliminar (definitiva o temporalmente) claro si borrar en `Categoria` sin borrar en `Productos` tendrás registros sin coincidencia/clasificación. Otra opción es que uses borrado lógico y no físico; todo conlleva labor de código según opción que elijas.

Comment: Te recomiendo elaborar bien la pregunta. Añade una captura de pantalla de las relaciones y de los datos que te da problemas. Me cuesta entender tu mención a "cuando yo elimino en 'categoria' un campo ingresado por el usuario". ¿Quién es el usuario? ¿A qué te refieres con campo? Porque que yo sepa, tu eliminas un campo de una tabla a nivel general, pero si le eliminas algo a un usuario, es una fila no un campo. Excepto que "borres" el contenido que un usuario ha puesto. Es muy confusa tu pregunta. Elabora por favor.

Comment: según entiendo deseas borrar una fila de la bd que hace referencia via fk con otra tabla, generalmente un borrado como ese te dara problemas de integridad en la base de datos al tener referencias que no apuntan a nada, puedes buscar el concepto drop cascade, pero como comento te puede generar problemas de integridad, lo otro es usar softdelete, este método añade un campo deleted_at con un timestamp y si este es null se muestra, caso contrario no se muestra

Answer (score 0):

Una de las características de los RDBMS (***R**elational **D**ata **B**ase **M**anagement **S**ystem*) es hacer cumplir y proteger la **Integridad Referencial**, que es a lo que los comentarios se refieren. Básicamente significa que **el motor de base de datos se debe asegurar que todas las referencias a otros objetos (ej. tablas) sean VÁLIDAS**. Si tú borras una categoría que ya ha sido utilizada en algún producto, la columna *IdCategoria* en la tabla *Producto* tendría una referencia inválida, porque no existiría, entonces el motor de base de datos prohibe la operación.

> como evito ese error?

Que sea claro: **No es un error.**

Basados en la explicación anterior, tienes dos caminos:

1. Puedes hacer un *Soft Delete* como @Ivo Olivares dijo:

Esto significa que en tu tabla Categoría tendrás una columna llamada "**Activo**", de tipo **BIT** (bool en C#), que te indicará si la categoría está activa y puede ser usada. De esta manera, cuando traigas las categorías, podrás filtrarlas adecuadamente.

Usando Entity Framework y LINQ:

```
 var categoria = _dbContext.Categoria.Where(c=> c.Activo).ToList();
```

2. Delete on Cascade:

Si escoges este camino, cuando borres una categoría, se borrarán todas las filas de la tabla Producto que tengan esta categoría, porque esas referencias serán inválidas. No es lo más recomendable, puesto que tal vez quieras guardara esos registros para auditoría, etc.; o incluso, puede que hayan otros objetos que dependan de otros registros de la tabla Producto y tengas que borrarlos primero (por eso se llama "en cascada").

Para permitir el Delete on Cascade en Entity Framework se puede hacer cuando estés creando el contexto con FluentAPI:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Producto>()
        .HasRequired(c => c.Categoria)
        .WithOptional(p => p.Productos)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

Puedes encontrar más información en [esta respuesta de Stack Overflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487577/entity-framework-ef-code-first-cascade-delete-for-one-to-zero-or-one-relations).

Casi todas las aplicaciones en las que he trabajado utilizan un soft delete. Borrar filas de las tablas de la base de datos no es un asunto trivial. Sugiero valores si quiere un Delete on Cascade o un Soft Delete.